custom positioning a leaflet control on different screen sizes
I have a rather simple leaflet control that shows the information about markers.
update: added code for the control
const info = L.control();
const initialMsg = 'Click on a marker for more info';

// create a div with a class "info"
info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    this._div.innerHTML = initialMsg;
    return this._div;
};

// this updates the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {

    this._div.innerHTML = …

};

info.addTo(map);

On a computer screen, the position of the control is top right as shown below.

I would like to change that position to as shown in the image below when viewing on a mobile phone.

Per the docs and some web searching, I am not sure if this kind of responsive positioning is possible with the controls. Is there some other option I can pursue to make this happen?

hmm… I never mentioned a plugin. It is just a normal control with the simplest of code that I've now added to the original message above

You can change all elements on the leaflet-control-container map using your own css.
You can create your own elements in leaflet-control-container see my example create-additional-control-placeholders You have exactly the element on the right which on a small phone you can change the position to the bottom using css.

From the Leaflet.js documentation, you can see that it is possible to move a control within the map container using setPosition(<string> position) where position seems to have one of four values:

topleft
topright
bottomleft
bottomright

However, this does not achieve what you want which is to position the control below the map container.
This post should be interesting for you: Placing controls outside map container with Leaflet? which explains how to move the control outside of the map container.
In addition to that, you will need a method to detect the device viewing your map and this is explained here, for example.

You could use a media query to change the control's width and height when the window size is smaller than a certain value. Here is an example (if window width is smaller than 600px):
.custom-control {
    
    --leaflet-control-margin: 10px;
    --control-padding: 1rem;
    
    background-color: white; 
    padding: var(--control-padding);

    /* this may need to have some adjustments */
    --deduction: calc(var(--control-padding)*2 
                    + var(--leaflet-control-margin)*2);

    max-width: calc(100vw - var(--deduction));
    max-height: calc(100vh - var(--deduction));

    /* enable scrolling if needed */
    overflow-y: auto;

}

@media (max-width: 600px) {

    .custom-control.data-populated {
        width: calc(100vw - var(--deduction));
    }

}

The example assumes that your root element of your control's HTML content has the class custom-control. And, the example assumes that your map uses the full width and height of the page and that your control is the first control in the top right corner of the map. Finally, it assumes that the margin of .leaflet-control (leaflet.css) is 10px.
If any of this does not apply to your web map, you'll need to adjust the CSS variable --deduction.
Here is a full working example (has some adjusted calculations to consider the zoom buttons):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>StackOverflow Question 79047918</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" />

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

    <style>

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #map { 
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .test-marker .circle {
            background-color: #f07819;
            border-radius: 50%;
            height: 20px; width: 20px;
        }

        .custom-control {
            
            --leaflet-control-margin: 10px;
            --control-padding: 1rem;
            --zoom-button-width: 42px; /* including borders */
            
            background-color: white; 
            padding: var(--control-padding);

            /* this may need to have some adjustments */
            --deduction: calc(var(--control-padding)*2 
                            + var(--leaflet-control-margin)*2);

            max-width: calc(100vw - var(--deduction) - var(--zoom-button-width));
            max-height: calc(100vh - var(--deduction));

            /* enable scrolling if needed */
            overflow-y: auto;

        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {

            .custom-control.data-populated {
                width: calc(100vw - var(--deduction) - var(--zoom-button-width));
            }

        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
        
        const coordinate = [46.43283, 9.76596];

        const map = L.map('map').setView(coordinate, 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            // add link to attribution, omitted in this code example
            // due to width limit, i.e., avoid horizontal scrolling
            attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap',
        }).addTo(map);

        const testMarker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(...coordinate), {
            icon: L.divIcon({
                className: 'test-marker',
                iconSize: [20, 20],
                html: '<div class="circle"></div>'
            }),
            
        }).addTo(map);

        const info = L.control();
        const initialMessage = 'Click on a marker for more info';

        info.onAdd = function(map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
            this._div.innerHTML = `
                <div class="custom-control">
                    ${initialMessage}
                </div>
            `;
            return this._div;
        };

        info.update = function(properties) {
            this._div.innerHTML = `
                <div class="custom-control data-populated">
                    Sils-Maria: ${properties.lat}, ${properties.lng}
                </div>
            `; 
        };

        testMarker.on('click', event => {
            info.update(event.latlng);
        });

        info.addTo(map);

    </script>

</body>
</html>


